# cordova add android platform!! error commant failed with exit code enoent at childprocess whendoen

Tags: cordova

when I try to add the android android platform to my cordova project, it is giving an error. My path is the following

```
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_21\bin;C:\Users\karan\Downloads\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20131030\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20131030\sdk\platform-tools;C:\Users\karan\Downloads\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20131030\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20131030\sdk\tools;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\110\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\110\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\110\DTS\Binn\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\110\Tools\Binn\ManagementStudio\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\IDE\PrivateAssemblies\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\110\DTS\Binn\;C:\Program Files (x86)\MySQL\MySQL Utilities 1.3.6\;C:\Program Files\nodejs\;C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\npm\;C:\Users\karan\Downloads\
adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20131030\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20131030\eclipse\plugins\org.apache.ant_1.8.3.v201301120609\bin
```

I am confused! Is this a problem with ant path

Comment: can u please tell me the version of cordova u are using?

Comment: I am using cordova 3.4.0..

Comment: with my experience in cordova/phonegap application, i encountered this error once when i did not navigate to cordova application directory before adding the platform.

Comment: I am in the directory where I store my application files. That is where I am trying to add these files.

Comment: can u add the screen shot of the error?